# How do I get such colorful plots with bar legends colored like this?

Tags: plotting, color, legending

[image: example]

Each line in this plot is for the same equation with different values of a parameter $\beta$; the range of $\beta$ is shown in the lines plotted and the bar legend. I want to know how to create such colorful plots. Any kind of example would be nice. Thank you.

Let's say I want to plot this equation:

```
\rho == (C (3 + C r^2))/(8 \[Pi] (1 + C r^2)^2 (1 + \[Beta]))
```

with `C = 0.00662391`, `r = [0, 12.5]` and `β = [0,0.5, 0.05]`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this?

```
c = 0.00662391;
ρ[r_, β_] = c (3 + c r^2)/(8 π (1 + c r^2)^2 (1 + β)) ;

{βmin, βmax, βinc} = {0, 0.5, 0.05};

colorscheme = "SolarColors";

βvals = Range[βmin, βmax, βinc];

βcolors = ColorData[colorscheme] /@ ((βvals - βmin)/(βmax -  βmin))

Plot[Evaluate[Table[ρ[r, β], {β, βvals}]], {r, 0, 12.5}, 
 PlotStyle -> βcolors, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{colorscheme, {βmin, βmax}}]]
```

[image]

The main idea here is to pre-calculate the $\beta$ values that will be used, feed them into a pre-defined color function to figure out the corresponding colors, and then supply the colors (and the legend) as options to `Plot`.

**EDIT**:  To include dashings, replace the last few lines of the code with something like the following.  The list `dashings` should be a list, with the same length as `βcolors`, specifying the dashing you want for each curve.  In the case below, I create a list that contains `Dashed` repeatedly, so that each curve becomes dashed.

```
    βcolors = ColorData[colorscheme] /@ ((βvals - βmin)/(βmax -  βmin));
    dashings = ConstantArray[Dashed, Length[βvals]];

    Plot[Evaluate[Table[ρ[r, β], {β, βvals}]], {r, 0, 12.5}, 
     PlotStyle -> Transpose[{βcolors, dashings}], 
     PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{colorscheme, {βmin, βmax}}]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was helpful. But I can not use another `PlotStyle`  other than the default one. Can you please help?

Comment: @BibhashDas I'm not clear on what you're asking for.  What `PlotStyle` do you want to use?  What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I want to use `PlotStyle`s like `Dashed` or `DotDashed`.

Comment: @BibhashDas:  See my edited answer.

Comment: @MichaleSeifert It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

`C` has a built-in meaning, use `c` instead

```
c = 0.00662391;

ρ = (c (3 + c r^2))/(8 π (1 + c r^2)^2 (1 + β));
```

With a [`BarLegend`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarLegend.html)

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[
   Tooltip[10^4 ρ, 
    StringForm["``=``", HoldForm[β], 
     NumberForm[β, {5, 2}]]], {β, 0, 0.5, 0.05}],
 {r, 0, 10},
 PlotStyle -> (ColorData["SolarColors"][2 #] & /@
    Range[0, 0.5, 0.05]),
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {
   StringForm["`` (km)", HoldForm[r]],
   StringForm["`` (x``\[ThinSpace]``)", HoldForm[ρ], 10^"-4", km^"-2"]},
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"SolarColors", {0, 0.5}},
   LegendLabel -> Style[HoldForm[β], 14]]]
```

[image]

With a [`LineLegend`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineLegend.html)

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[Tooltip[10^4 ρ,
    StringForm["``=``", HoldForm[β], 
     NumberForm[β, {5, 2}]]], {β, 0, 0.5, 0.05}],
 {r, 0, 10},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {
   StringForm["`` (km)", HoldForm[r]],
   StringForm["`` (x``\[ThinSpace]``)", HoldForm[ρ], 10^"-4", km^"-2"]},
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Range[0, 0.5, 0.05],
   LegendLayout -> {"Column", 2},
   LegendLabel -> Style[HoldForm[β], 14]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help.